# Invoking method "Find" on unknown DbSet throws: "Object does not match target."

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to run method "Find" on unknown DbSet. And find a record which name is "string". I do it this way:

```
PropertyInfo prop = db.GetType().GetProperty(myClass);
Type classObject = prop.GetValue(db).GetType();
var classObjectMethod = classObject.GetMethods().Last(x=>x.Name=="Find");
var record = classObjectMethod.Invoke(classObject, new object[] { new object[] {"string"} });
```

It throws "System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Object does not match target type.'" and I don't know why. How can I make this work?

Comment: We don't have `db` nor `myClass` which means *we can't run this code*. Given the typo that was present (that you fixed within the grace period), it's unlikely that *you have run this code either*. Please create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're using came from the `classObject`, but: `classObject` is badly named - that is actually the *type* of the object (see : `.GetType()`). You want the *instance*, not the type; so:

```cs
PropertyInfo prop = db.GetType().GetProperty(myClass);
object classObject = prop.GetValue(db);
var classObjectMethod = classObject.GetType().GetMethods().Last(x=>x.Name=="Find");
var record = classObjectMethod.Invoke(classObject, new object[] { new object[] {"string"} });
```

The important bit here is that I've moved the `.GetType()`, so that `classObject` remains the target instance.

Comment: Thank you. I've been chasing my tail on this for a day.